# ANTLR tokenizing works with space, but not without

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I'm trying to figure out this bug. Currently, when I supply a few different inputs, I get either the correct result, or the ANTLRWorks debugger loops infinitely.

```
1) {v0, p1} = Infinite loop or mismatched token exception
2) {v0..v1} Works!
3) {v0,p1} Works? Why?! Notice the lack of space?
```

If anyone could help me understand why this is ambiguous, I'd really appreciate it. I've tried changing operator precedence, and still, I cannot get it to work the way I think it should. Thank you!

```
    WHITESPACE    :  ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };
    LEFTCURL      : '{';
    RIGHTCURL     : '}';
    REGISTER      : ('v'|'p') NUMBER+;

    REGISTERLIST  : LEFTCURL REGISTER (',' REGISTER)* RIGHTCURL;
    REGISTERANGE  : LEFTCURL REGISTER '..' REGISTER RIGHTCURL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHITESPACE`s are only put on the `HIDDEN` channel inside parser rules. Since both `REGISTERLIST` and `REGISTERANGE` are lexer rules, the spaces are not hidden, as you noticed. Instead of accounting for spaces inside these rules, these look to be more suitable as parser rules:

```
registerList  : LEFTCURL REGISTER (',' REGISTER)* RIGHTCURL;
registerRange : LEFTCURL REGISTER '..' REGISTER RIGHTCURL;
```

Comment: I had this epiphany when I was riding my bike home yesterday and had not yet had a chance to try it out. Thanks so much for the advice!